# Event Queues and Microtask Queues

Tags: dart, flutter

In the Dart documentation [The Event Loop and Dart (2013)](https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop#how-to-schedule-a-task) it mentions that any `Future` is added to the `Event` queue.

It also mentions that `Microtask` queues are meant to always run first, then `Event` queues.

This documentation is old, and seems geared towards web development so I'm not sure if this is different for Flutter as when I do this code.

```
Future<String> myFunction() => new Future.value('Hello');
Future<String> myFunction2() => new Future.value('Hello2');
Future<void> mainTest() async {
  debugPrint("Sync1");  
  myFunction().then(debugPrint);
  scheduleMicrotask(() { debugPrint("Microtask"); });
  myFunction2().then(debugPrint);  
  debugPrint("Sync2");
}
```

I get an output of

```
I/flutter ( 6731): Sync1
I/flutter ( 6731): Sync2
I/flutter ( 6731): Hello
I/flutter ( 6731): Microtask
I/flutter ( 6731): Hello2
```

But if all Microtasks were meant to be run before the next Event loop, shouldn't it be this?

```
I/flutter ( 6731): Sync1
I/flutter ( 6731): Sync2
I/flutter ( 6731): Microtask // This running first before the Futures?
I/flutter ( 6731): Hello
I/flutter ( 6731): Hello2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be the case if you were invoking methods without calling `.then`

> A way to add a task to the microtask queue is to invoke then() on a
>   Future that’s already complete.

So when you call  `myFunction().then(print);` future is added to microtask queue.

Some bonus facts for the cases when calling without '`.then`':
According to the [docs](https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop#microtask-queue-schedulemicrotask) there were 2 bugs. **These bugs were fixed, but the issue still remains :(**

> The upshot of these bugs: The first task that you schedule with
>   scheduleMicrotask() seems like it’s on the event queue.
>
> A workaround is to put your first call to scheduleMicrotask() before
>   your first call to new Future()

Comment: But those bugs were closed and also if I keep doing multiple scheduleMicrotasks, it continues to exhibit the same issue. All the scheduleMicrotasks, are done between the 2 Hello's.

Comment: @AdamPedley updated my answer. Good observation I was looking a the examples in the documentation. Ran your code, did some digging found the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Notes for the general reader:

- The Event Loop has two queues of tasks: the Microtask Queue and the Event Queue.
- Any tasks in the Microtask Queue are always run before the next task in the Event Queue.
- Microtasks are generally scheduled by the system while Event Queue tasks generally come from the outside events (IO, app events, etc.).

I believe the following points explain the behavior that you are observing:

- The `Future.value()` constructor schedules a microtask on the Microtask Queue.
- The `Future()` constructor, on the other hand, schedules a regular task on the Event Queue.

The original link you shared is only available as an archive now:

- [The Event Loop and Dart](https://web.archive.org/web/20170704074724/https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop)

It is still worth reading, though.