# Slower execution time in async main with nested loops as an example

Tags: dart

I have a question related to the performance difference. When I use a nested loop in the main function, it takes some time to complete. However, when I tag this function with the async keyword, the execution time gets longer. I have read a lot of information on this topic in several forums, but I still have trouble understanding the difference. If anyone can explain it to me very simply, I will be grateful.

Thank you

```
void main() {
  final sw = Stopwatch()..start();
  for (int i = 0; i < 30000; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; ++j) {}
    if (i % 1000 == 0) print(i);
  }
  print(sw.elapsed.inSeconds); // Execution time: 1 second
}
```

is faster than:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final sw = Stopwatch()..start();
  for (int i = 0; i < 30000; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; ++j) {}
    if (i % 1000 == 0) print(i);
  }
  print(sw.elapsed.inSeconds); // Execution time: 9 seconds
}
```

Comment: I can see huge difference only visually using just VisualStudioCode. Should I measure it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting, as `async` is not supposed to start any asynchronous processing until it has to. This question [Event Queues and Microtask Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54180637/event-queues-and-microtask-queues) has an interesting discussion and links.

Changing the async version by replacing `async` with an explicit `Future()` constructor reduces the overhead considerably:

```
Future<void> loop2() {
  return Future<void>(() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30000; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 100000; ++j) {}
      if (i % 1000 == 0) print(i);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I read the links you indicated, thanks to which I learned a few new things that I had not come across before. The code example was also helpful. Nevertheless, what interests me the most now is the need to understand why there is such a time difference in my example. What mechanism in the dart language is responsible for what we observe - step by step. What is behind such a simple code that even when run in a terminal gives the same effect.